# Implementing advanced search with And and Or keyword search

Tags: c#, linq

I have a textbox in which the user can type keywords to search for by including `and` and `or` keywords to make the keywords work like a SQL Filter. How can I perform this type of search using Linq? If possible, please also take parentheses (`()`) into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

If it's going to be free text entry, e.g.

`LastName = "Smith" and FirstName = "John"`

then you may find it helpful to use Scott Guthrie's [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) library, which provides a `Where()` method that accepts a string that it parses into a lambda. Then you could do something like this:

```
string searchQuery = GetSearchQueryFromTextBox();
var searchResult = customers.Where(searchQuery);
```

It supports the `and` and `or` operators, as shown above, as well as parentheses and host of other operators and methods.

Comment: Thanks, if I were asking this, instead of reading this question, I would have marked this as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
from s in search 
where 
  ((s.operatorKeyword == "and" && (s.property1 == "1" && s.property2 == "2")) || 
   (s.operatorKeyword == "or"  && (s.property1 == "1" || s.property2 == "2")))
select s
```